# VS2010 "No tests were impacted"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I have a TFS build in VS2010. Following the build unit tests are executed. In the Build summary it tells me that "1 test run(s) completed - 100% average pass rate" but below this it states "No tests were impacted". I guess Impacted Tests relate to functionality providing the ability to only run tests that were impacted by code checked in? Is this correct and since I'm happy to run all tests following each build, how can I turn off the "No tests were impacted" message?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about test impact analysis - it looks at the changesets since the last build and which tests intersect with that code. To disable test impact analysis for a build:

1. Right-click your build definition in Team Explorer and choose Edit...
2. Go to the Process category and expand the Advanced section
3. Set "Analyze Test Impact" to False

You can also set this value on a per-build basis - queue a manual build and the setting is available via the Parameters tab.